# Pybrain version installed?

Tags: version, pybrain

How do I know which pybrain version I have installed in my machine? For instance, if i want to know which numpy version I have, I simply type:

import numpy

print numpy.version.version

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("pybrain").version
```

### Alternative

1. Find out if it's installed at all: `pydoc modules | grep pybrain`
2. There seems to be only version 0.3 out (see [source](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain)).

When you get into the Python console and type

```
>>> import pybrain
>>> help(pybrain)
```

You get

```
Help on package pybrain:

NAME
    pybrain

FILE
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybrain/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    auxiliary (package)
    datasets (package)
    optimization (package)
    rl (package)
    structure (package)
    supervised (package)
    tests (package)
    tools (package)
    unsupervised (package)
    utilities
```

So take a look at the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` folder. In my case, there is a `PyBrain-0.3.egg-info` that indicates that I have PyBrain 0.3.